# C# Properties visible at runtime but not compile time?

Tags: c#, lambda, runtime, compile-time

I have the following code in a Web API call.

```
IEnumerable<WebSite> result;

using (var mgr = new ServerManager()) {
    result = mgr.Sites.Select(s => new WebSite {
        Name = s.Name, 
        LogLocation = s.LogFile.Directory,
        LogDirs = s.Applications.Select(a=> 
            string.Format("{0}\\W3SVC{1}", s.LogFile.Directory, a.Site.Id)
            ).ToList()
    }).ToList();
}
```

I'm trying to enumerate the directories of the IIS logs.  In the second lambda, `a.Site.Id` is invalid at compile time because `a` has no `Site` property.  However, setting a breakpoint in that lambda and looking at the members or calling that code in the Immediate Window works just fine.  Any idea what is happening here?

Comment: That means that the compile-time type and runtime type are different.

Comment: That was my first guess, but for the life of me I can't figure out exactly what type is being exposed to the debugger.  If I can cast it to whatever that type is, I'll be in business.

Comment: Does the compile time type of `Site` property has the `Id` property?

Comment: Look at the third column of the watch window

Comment: It seems that at both compile and runtime, the type of `a` is `Microsoft.Web.Administration.Application`, yet that type has no `Site` property.